# Difficulties retrieving data with SQL now() function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to retrieve some data utilising SQL's `now()` function. It works problem free for monthly and weekly queries. However, when I try to pull daily data, the numbers are way off. Sample code I am using:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(distinct be.booking_id)AS "Number of Inquiries"
FROM booking_events be
WHERE be.event = 'inquire' 
AND DATE_PART('day', be.created_at) = DATE_PART('day', now())
```

I tried figuring it out for a couple of days, but without any luck.

Comment: do you want only todays data? is it? then `date_trunc('day',created_at), date_trunc('day',now())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, if you want today's data, I might suggest:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct be.booking_id)AS "Number of Inquiries"
FROM booking_events be
WHERE be.event = 'inquire' AND
      be.created_at >= current_date and
      be.created_at < current_date + interval '1 day';
```

I don't think `date_part()` helps you unless you want all records from the same *day of the month* -- say, Jan 25, Feb 25, Mar 25, and so on.

You might be thinking of `date_trunc()` instead:

```
WHERE be.event = 'inquire' AND
      date_trunc(be.created_at) = current_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Please explain what is your problem - here's example of working query you say does not work:

[image]
**EDIT:**

```
select created_at,extract(day from created_at),DATE_PART('day', now()),extract(day from now()),now() from be where DATE_PART('day', be.created_at) = DATE_PART('day', now())
```

[image]

**EDIT2**

just in case you are trying to compare today agaist date in row, then use `date_trunc`, like:

```
select date_trunc('day',created_at), date_trunc('day',now()) from be ;
```

Comment: I just explained it. The data retrieved by above query does not match the actual records. Thanks for providing a detailed answer, though.

Comment: sorry - must be late hours. I don't get what does not match. anyway if my answer does not help - ignore it